# Pairs of integers in array with distance conditions.

Tags: algorithms

We are given a positive integer $n>0$.
I want to build an array of integers of size $2n+1$ that satisfies the conditions :

- The number $0$ appears **once**.
- For each number $1\leq k \leq n$, the number $k$ appears **twice** and the number of elements between those values is exactly equal to $k$.

For example :

- For $n = 1$ :  $[1, 0, 1]$ is a valid solution.
- For $n = 2$ : $[2, 0, 1, 2, 1]$
- For $n = 3$ : $[3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 0]$
- For $n = 4$ : $[4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 2, 0]$
- For $n = 5$ : $[5, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 3, 1]$
- For $n = 6$ : $[6, 3, 5, 2, 4, 3, 2, 6, 5, 4, 1, 0, 1]$

For now, I have an algorithm that uses backtracking but is inefficient for large values of $n$.

I suspect there is a constructive *linear* solution.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The task has been updated.

Answer (score 2):

Nest all odd numbers less than $n$ into one subarray, and all even numbers less than $n$ into another subarray with the $0$ closer to the beginning. Each subarray has a term to be determined.

Concatenate the two arrays together. There are exactly $n$ elements between the two missing terms, because each of $0,1,2,\ldots, n-1$ exists once between the two missing terms.

Then it's valid to set the missing terms to both be $n$.

---

For example $n=6$: Concatenate $[5,3,1,?,1,3,5]$ and $[4,2,0,?,2,4]$, and both the $?$ terms can be set to $6$.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you.
For those who are wondering, if $n$ is odd for example $n=5$, then :

$[4, 2, ?, 0, 2, 4]$ and $[3, 1, ?, 1, 3]$-> $[4, 2, 5, 0, 2, 4, 3, 1, 5, 1, 3]$

Comment: @alatiahmad Thanks. For the odd $n$ case, I intended to follow the same (arbitrary) order where the odd subarray is before the even subarray, (e.g. for $n=5$: $[3,1,5,1,3,4,2,0,5,2,4]$), so I didn't give a separate example.